# Reuse environmental variables from shell file in a batch file

Tags: shell, batch-file, parameters

I have a .sh file containing parameters, my question is how I obtain those variables in a batch file?.

This is a sample of my .sh file with contains parameters:

```
PRM_Servidor=dwh_desa                       ;export PRM_Servidor            #SERVIDOR TERADATA
PRM_Usuario=TCH_CARGA_FULL                  ;export PRM_Usuario             #USUARIO TERADATA
PRM_Passwd=tchcarga2010                     ;export PRM_Passwd              #PASSWORD TERADATA
PRM_Servidor=dwh_desa                       ;export PRM_Servidor            #SERVIDOR TERADATA
PRM_Usuario=TCH_CARGA_FULL                  ;export PRM_Usuario             #USUARIO TERADATA
PRM_Passwd=tchcarga2010                     ;export PRM_Passwd              #PASSWORD TERADATA
```

I just want to get these parameters to a batch file

Comment: .sh files generally don't run on Windows; how are you planning on running both scripts on the same machine?

Comment: I have a UnixUtils installed on windows this allows me to run .sh files, but
I just want to get the parameters not run a .sh file.

Comment: @MatiasAraya, you will have to provide more details in your question.  Please edit your question and provide as much information as you possibly can think of that will help us help you.

Comment: @MatiasAraya, what makes those lines unique from the rest of your .SH script so that we know to pull only those lines and not other lines that may contain some of those variable names as well.

Comment: assuming the var=value list above is your input, please edit your Q to show what you need as output (don't post code to comments). OR are you asking "what do I need for bat to perform the same function?". Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this comment: **;export PRM_** will only ever be on lines that are setting variables and your variable names and variable values do not have spaces you could use the following code.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%G IN ('findstr /C:";export PRM_" mybash.sh') DO SET %%G
SET PRM_
PAUSE
```